# Ember tagless component innerhtml

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components

I have a tagless component in Ember and want to have the innerHtml (`this.element`) on a lifecycle hook (for example the didRender). When I use `this.element` the value is always `null`. When I add a tagname to the component (`tagName: 'div'`) I have the innerHtml of the component with `this.element`, but can I get the innerHtml without setting the tagName?

Comment: I’m not sure, but I think that’s the price of tagless components. Why do you need to have a tagless component? Maybe there’s another way you can accomplish the same goal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this.element` does not give you `innerHTML`, it gives you a real HTML `Element`. A tagless component, by definition, doesn't have any `Element` of its own. So `this.element` is necessarily null.

The biggest reason we haven't added an equivalent property for retrieving a `Range` (which is what you'd need to represent a tagless component's area of the DOM) is that unlike `this.element`, the `Range` could change through the lifetime of the component. Making it fully observable would be expensive, and leaving it not-observable would make it really easy to create bugs.

Most of the common use cases are covered by what Gaurav suggested: explicitly labeling the elements you really want to find and accessing them via `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`.

If you're doing something really fancy, and you understand that it's only a snapshot that can go stale, the escape hatch is `Ember.ViewUtils.getViewBounds`. It's not marked public, but it is depended on by official projects like Ember Inspector, so we absolutely would not break it without warning. Like any heavily-used non-public API, we would issue a deprecation warning and wait a full LTS cycle.

In the case of `Ember.ViewUtils.getViewBounds`, a strong case can be made for just marking it public, and if somebody writes an RFC to that effect I think we can get consensus on that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is broken. See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13627 for more details.

A workaround has been posted here: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/issues/168 However, it uses private apis and may break in future versions without warning.

My recommendation is to either use an element via tagName so `this.element` exists, or to place a class on the component's parent element so that you can use `document.querySelector('.class-name').innerHTML` -- but this requires that the parent element be known.

Comment: That issue is about `elementId`, not `element`, though I would argue in both cases it doesn't really make sense to ask for `this.element` of a tagless component -- there _is_ no element to return to you.